# generic CMP preprocessor macro

Tags: c

rather than having lots of cmp type functions for all your numeric datatypes

could you just use the preprocessor and have something like:

```
#define CMP(a, b) ((a > b) - (a < b))
```

and then:

```
int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types
    const int *ib = (const int *)b;

    return CMP(*ia, *ib);
}

int double_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const double *ia = (const double *)a;
    const double *ib = (const double *)b;

    return CMP(*ia, *ib);
}
```

etc. for all numeric datatypes you are interested in..

Comment: Yes, but you get double evaluation bugs, and you should probably parenthesize `a` and `b` where they occur in the macro.

Comment: maybe this is generally not the done thing as there are too many subtle ways that it can break?